# Fill an multidimensional array with a foreach

Tags: php

I need to make an array like this

```
   $preferenceData = [
            'items' => [
                [
                    'id' => 1,
                    'title' => 'Recarga de Créditos',
                    'description' => 'Recarga de Créditos para Negocioson.com',
                    'quantity' => 1,
                    'currency_id' => 'ARS',
                    'unit_price' => $amount
                ]
            ]
        ];
```

But I need to create it with a foreach

```
 foreach ($items as $item) {

}
```

I tried this:

```
$data[0]['items'][0]['id'] = 1;
```

BUT the results are not the same:

This is mine:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [items] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 1 ) ) ) )
```

This is the preference one:

```
Array ( [items] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 1 ) ) )
```

I add a `[0]` how can I delete it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use `$data[0]`. The top-level array is an associative array, not numeric.

```
$data['items'][0] = [
    'id' => 1,
    'title' => 'Recarga de Créditos',
    'description' => 'Recarga de Créditos para Negocioson.com',
    'quantity' => 1,
    'currency_id' => 'ARS',
    'unit_price' => $amount
];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
$data = [];
foreach ($items as $item) {
    $data['items'][] = [
        'id' => $item['id'],
        'title' => $item['title'],
        ...
    ];
}
```